# Listview in Fragment is causing Memory Leak

Tags: android

I have a FragmentActivity with a `FragmentMediaOverview` containing a list of `MediaItemView`s (each with a imageview and some text) and a click on one of the items opening a detail-Fragment.
Now when I go back (via back button) and forth (click on listitem) several times from list to detail fragment I eventually run into OOM-Errors. I use `SoftReference`s for the bitmaps in the listitems as well as in the detail fragment.
According to MAT there is an incresing number of `MediaItemView`s as well as `FragmentMediaOverview` instances, but I just cannot figure out why.

I read this [Android: AlertDialog causes a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083441/android-alertdialog-causes-a-memory-leak/) , but couldn't solve it `null`ing out listeners.

Here is my code:

FragmentMediaOverview.java

(This is not a ListFragment because for a tablet-layout the `MediaAdapter` needs to connect to a gridview)

```
public class FragmentMediaOverview extends Fragment {
    private static String TAG = FragmentMediaOverview.class.getSimpleName();

    private MediaAdapter adapter;
    private OnMediaSelectedListener selListener;
    private ArrayList<BOObject> mediaItems;

    private ViewGroup layoutContainer;    
    private AdapterView itemContainer; // list or gridview

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        layoutContainer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media_overview, null);

        return layoutContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        selListener = (OnMediaSelectedListener) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        itemContainer.setOnItemClickListener(null);
        selListener = null;
        adapter = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initUi(layoutContainer);
        displayMedia();
    }

    private void initUi(ViewGroup layoutContainer) {
        itemContainer = (AdapterView) layoutContainer.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        itemContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                BOMedia mediaItem = ((BOMedia) mediaItems.get(position));
//the FragmentActivity is coordinating the FragmentTransactions
                selListener.onMediaSelected(mediaItem);
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayMedia() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Displaying List");
        if (mediaItems == null) {
            loadMedia();
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "List: " + mediaItems.size() + ", adapter: " + itemContainer.getAdapter());

        if (adapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Create Adapter with " + mediaItems.size());

            adapter = new MediaAdapter(getActivity(), mediaItems);
        }

        if (itemContainer.getAdapter() == null) {
            itemContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            adapter.setItems(mediaItems);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    private void loadMedia() {
        FragmentHelper.showProgressSpinner(layoutContainer, android.R.id.list);
        DbHelper.getInstance().getMedia(mediaType, new DbQueryFinishListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDbCallFinish(ArrayList<BOObject> objects) {
                if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                    mediaItems = objects;
                    Collections.sort(mediaItems, new Comparator<BOObject>() {
                        final Collator c = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
                        @Override
                        public int compare(BOObject s1, BOObject s2) {
                            if (s2 != null && ((BOMedia) s2).getTitle() != null && s1 != null
                                    && ((BOMedia) s1).getTitle() != null) {
                                return c.compare(((BOMedia) s1).getTitle(),((BOMedia) s2).getTitle());
                            } else {
                                return 0;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    displayMedia();
                    FragmentHelper.hideProgressSpinner(layoutContainer, android.R.id.list);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDbCallException(Exception exception) {
                if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                    FragmentHelper.hideProgressSpinner(layoutContainer, android.R.id.list);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

MediaAdapter.java

```
public class MediaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = MediaAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<BOObject> mediaItems;

    public MediaAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BOObject> mediaItems) {
        super();
        context = c;
        this.mediaItems = mediaItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mediaItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new MediaItemView(context);
        }
        ((MediaItemView)convertView).initialize((BOMedia) mediaItems.get(position));        
        return convertView;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<BOObject> mediaItems) {
        this.mediaItems = mediaItems;
    }
}
```

MediaItemView.java

```
public class MediaItemView extends LinearLayout {
    private static final String TAG = MediaItemView.class.getSimpleName();
    private BOMedia item;
    private SoftReference<Bitmap> bm;
    private ImageView iv;
    private Context ctx;

    public MediaItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_media_item, this);
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    /** Init the view with a new BOMedia object
     * @param mediaItem
     */
    public void initialize(BOMedia mediaItem) {
        this.item = mediaItem;
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

        title.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getTitle()));
        iv.setImageBitmap(null);
        bm = null;
        System.gc();
        iv.invalidate();
        if (item.getFilepathThumb() != null && !item.getFilepathThumb().equals("")) {

            ExpansionPackManager.getInstance().getBitmapResource(item.getFilepathThumb(), false,
                    new BitmapReadListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFileRead(BitmapResponseMessage message) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap read: " + message.getFilepath());
                            Bitmap image = message.getBitmap();
                            if (image != null && message.getFilepath().equals(item.getFilepathThumb())) {
                                bm = new SoftReference<Bitmap>(image);
                                iv.setImageBitmap(bm.get());
                                Log.d(TAG, "image set");
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "image too late: " + image);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFileException(Throwable exception) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "image exception");
                        }
                    });

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a Look on it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933783/double-checking-if-fragment-view-holder-pattern-is-implemented-properly And I prefere you to watch the [Google IO presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) about `ListViews`. It contains memory saving techniques and it helped you to solve and understand the logic of the `ListViews`. And Also see this [PDF File.](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf)

Comment: Ideas: `ExpansionPackManager` might be holding references to bitaps or else `BitmapResponseMessage`s if they are maintained in a recycle pool like Android `Message`.  For the latter some other code would have to call `message.recycle()`.

Answer (score 2):

In MediaItemView the size of your bitmap must be too big. If the bitmap is 600x600 and you want to display a image with a size of 50x50 you can use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`. You should also use bitmap cache while loading your bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `View` for rach child in the `ListView` is recreated as you scroll through. This is very heavy on resources. To avoid this use a holder class in adapters `getView()` to hold and reuse the views.  This is called an `Efficient Adapter`. For example see `Efficient List Adapter` in `API demos`. http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This might make it a little more efficient, but wouldn't explain a memory leak would it?! As I am reusing the convertView, there shouldn't be any dead ones floating around...
I have the feeling that somehow the list items are being reinstantiating on a resume /back press, but old ones are being kept ...somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated = true
```

Beginning in `Android 3.0 (API level 11)`, the `Android 2D` rendering pipeline is designed to better support hardware acceleration. Hardware acceleration carries out all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas using the `GPU`.

For more info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html